# Solving a system of 2nd order differential equations from sympy

Tags: scipy, sympy, ode, differential-equations

I am doing a multiple DOF dynamics problem, using 2nd order Lagrangian equations. I used sympy to get to the equations of motion. Now these equations after calculating the derivatives got quite long, seems though that sympy simplify cant simplify it further.  My problem actually is how to solve this system of three 2nd order ode from here. I don't know how to get these equations converted so they can be used with scipy.odeint(). Substitution came to mind, but there are a lot of symbols. So Im searching for phi0,phi1 and phi2 and also for their first and second derivatives. Initial conditions are all phi[0]=0 and all dphi[0]=0. 
I hope there is a way to solve this without going from scratch. Thanks in advance.

```
def derivativeLagranga(Lagrange,n):
"""left side of lagrange"""
f0 = sym.Function('f0')(t)
f1 = sym.Function('f1')(t)
f2 = sym.Function('f2')(t)
f3 = sym.Function('f3')(t)
L_i = []
L_it = []
L_j =[]
L_leva = []
x=0
y=0
for i in range(0,n-1):
    x = Lagrange.diff(kot[i].diff(t))
    L_i.append(x)
for i in range(0,n-1):
    x = L_i[i].diff(t)
    x = x.replace(sym.sin(kot[i]),kot[i])
    L_it.append(x)
for i in range(0,n-1):
    x = L.diff(kot[i])
    L_j.append(x)

for i in range(0,n-1):
    x = L_it[i]+L_j[i]
    L_leva.append(x)



return L_left

left_side_L = derivativeLagranga(Lagrange, n)

f0 = sym.simplify(left_side_L[0].subs(values))
f1 = leva_stran_L[1].subs(values)
f2 = leva_stran_L[2].subs(values)

f0
```

So my f0 is the one of the equations, I couldn't copy the output so I will post a picture.

```
54.51345(−(0()+1()−2())sin(0()+1()−2())+2.00()0())(0.5(0()+1()−2())cos(0()+1()−2())−1.0cos(0())0()−1.0cos(1())1()+1.0cos(2())2())+54.51345((0()+1()−2())cos(0()+1()−2())+cos(0())0())(0.5(0()+1()−2())sin(0()+1()−2())+0.50()0()+0.5sin(1())1()+1.0sin(2())2())+54.51345(2.0(0()+1()−2())cos(0()+1()−2())+cos(0())0())(1.0(0()+1()−2())sin(0()+1()−2())+0.50()0()+0.5sin(1())1()+1.0sin(2())2()+0.5sin(4())4())−54.51345(2.0cos(0())0()+1.0cos(1())1())0()0()+54.51345(0()+sin(0()+1()−2()))((0.50()+0.51()−0.52())(0()+1()−2())cos(0()+1()−2())+(0.5220()+0.5221()−0.5222())sin(0()+1()−2())+0.50()220()+0.5sin(1())221()+1.0sin(2())222()+0.5cos(0())(0())2+0.5cos(1())(1())2+1.0cos(2())(2())2)+54.51345(0()+2.0sin(0()+1()−2()))((0()+1()−2())(1.00()+1.01()−1.02())cos(0()+1()−2())+(1.0220()+1.0221()−1.0222())sin(0()+1()−2())+0.50()220()+0.5sin(1())221()+1.0sin(2())222()+0.5sin(4())224()+0.5cos(0())(0())2+0.5cos(1())(1())2+1.0cos(2())(2())2+0.5cos(4())(4())2)+54.51345(cos(0()+1()−2())−2.0cos(0()))(−(0.50()+0.51()−0.52())(0()+1()−2())sin(0()+1()−2())+(0.5220()+0.5221()−0.5222())cos(0()+1()−2())+1.00()(0())2+1.0sin(1())(1())2−1.0sin(2())(2())2−1.0cos(0())220()−1.0cos(1())221()+1.0cos(2())222())+54.51345(0.50()0()+0.5sin(1())1()+0.5sin(2())2())cos(0())0()−54.51345(2.0cos(0())0()+2.0cos(1())1()−1.0cos(2())2())0()0()+54.51345(−2.00()(0())2−1.0sin(1())(1())2+2.0cos(0())220()+1.0cos(1())221())cos(0())+54.51345(−2.00()(0())2−2.0sin(1())(1())2+1.0sin(2())(2())2+2.0cos(0())220()+2.0cos(1())221()−1.0cos(2())222())cos(0())+54.51345(0.50()220()+0.5sin(1())221()+0.5sin(2())222()+0.5cos(0())(0())2+0.5cos(1())(1())2+0.5cos(2())(2())2)0()−2123.4060()+45.427875220()−2123.4061()+9.085575221()−9.085575222()
```

And lambdify output:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-ee077b324a2e> in <module>
      2 en2 = sym.lambdify([kot_0,kot_1,kot_2],f1)
      3 en3 = sym.lambdify([kot_0,kot_1,kot_2],f2)
----> 4 en1(kot_0,kot_1,kot_2)
      5 
      6 

<lambdifygenerated-4> in _lambdifygenerated(_Dummy_227, _Dummy_226, _Dummy_225)
      9   # Derivative
     10   # Derivative
---> 11 22.722525*_Dummy_227**2*Derivative(_Dummy_227, (t, 2)) + 90.8901*_Dummy_227*(-0.5*cos(_Dummy_226)*Derivative(_Dummy_226, t) - 1.0*cos(_Dummy_227)*Derivative(_Dummy_227, t))*Derivative(_Dummy_227, t) + 90.8901*_Dummy_227*(0.5*cos(_Dummy_225)*Derivative(_Dummy_225, t) - 1.0*cos(_Dummy_226)*Derivative(_Dummy_226, t) - 1.0*cos(_Dummy_227)*Derivative(_Dummy_227, t))*Derivative(_Dummy_227, t) - 22.722525*_Dummy_227*(-_Dummy_227*Derivative(_Dummy_227, (t, 2)) - sin(_Dummy_225)*Derivative(_Dummy_225, (t, 2)) - sin(_Dummy_226)*Derivative(_Dummy_226, (t, 2)) - cos(_Dummy_225)*Derivative(_Dummy_225, t)**2 - cos(_Dummy_226)*Derivative(_Dummy_226, t)**2 - cos(_Dummy_227)*Derivative(_Dummy_227, t)**2) + 0.5*Jm*(-2*Derivative(_Dummy_225, (t, 2)) + 2*Derivative(_Dummy_226, (t, 2)) + 2*Derivative(_Dummy_227, (t, 2))) + 1.0*Jm*Derivative(_Dummy_227, (t, 2)) + 45.44505*(-1.0*_Dummy_227 - 2.0*sin(-_Dummy_225 + _Dummy_226 + _Dummy_227))*(-0.5*_Dummy_227*Derivative(_Dummy_227, (t, 2)) + (-Derivative(_Dummy_225, t) + Derivative(_Dummy_226, t) + Derivative(_Dummy_227, t))*(1.0*Derivative(_Dummy_225, t) - 1.0*Derivative(_Dummy_226, t) - 1.0*Derivative(_Dummy_227, t))*cos(-_Dummy_225 + _Dummy_226 + _Dummy_227) + (1.0*Derivative(_Dummy_225, (t, 2)) - 1.0*Derivative(_Dummy_226, (t, 2)) - 1.0*Derivative(_Dummy_227, (t, 2)))*sin(-_Dummy_225 + _Dummy_226 + _Dummy_227) - 1.0*sin(_Dummy_225)*Derivative(_Dummy_225, (t, 2)) - 0.5*sin(_Dummy_226)*Derivative(_Dummy_226, (t, 2)) - 0.5*sin(varphi_4(t))*Der
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfNo9.jpg

EDIT2: So after a lof of simplification i some how got 3 ordinary differential equations. But they are in sympy form, how can i solve them numericaly?

```
−800000.00+800000.02−1770.174˙0+242.3736¨0−1770.174˙1+166.63185¨1−75.74175¨2+4245.8661 

−1200000.01+400000.02−1770.174˙0+166.63185¨0−1770.174˙1+151.4835¨1−75.74175¨2+2830.5774 

800000.00+400000.01−2000000.02−75.74175¨0−75.74175¨1+60.5934¨2−1415.2887
```

Comment: The code you have provided is incomplete so I can't test it but for numerical integration you will want to use lambdify.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin Hi, so i tried lambdify, but my expresions contain derivative of the phi. In style like "Derivative(varphi_0(t), t)". Do you have any hint with that? PS: Is there a way for me to post my whole code?

Comment: You are aware that the last index in `range(0,n-1)` is `n-2`?

Comment: Don't post your whole code. Post a simpler but *complete* version. All you need is to show an example of what f0, f1, and f2 are so most of the other code is unnecessary in order to ask for help with this.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin The output of f0 is in the picture. But i will add the copy also.

Comment: Are you aware that sympy.physics.mechanics exists with some routines to extract the ODE system from the Lagrange function?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I saw documentation of sympy.physics.mechanics, but the intergrating it seemed very difficult, so i did it manually. If you have a good example or a video of sympy.physics.mechanics  being used, please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A picture is no good. I need the code so that I can get the same objects that you are working with. The code provided has too much information (I just need the repr of f0, f1, and f2) and at the same time too little (it doesn't run on its own)/

Answer (score 2):

I'll present the execution of the Euler-Lagrange formalism for the example of the double pendulum as a non-trivial, complete, standard example, and this without using the specialized functions in sympy.physics, only using basic differentiation and code-writing facilities of sympy. Hopefully it is general enough in that the second part should be problem-independent and thus also be directly applicable to your situation.

```py
from sympy import sin, cos, Symbol, symbols, solve
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify
```

### Lagrangian for the physical model

First the physical setup for the Lagrangian using the two angles as the main dependent functions and construct kinetic and potential energy via the Cartesian coordinates.

```py
# Symbols for the parameters of the problem
t,m1,m2,l1,l2,g = symbols("t,m_1 m_2 l_1 l_2 g")
# Variables of the problem
th1, th2 = Function("θ_1")(t), Function("θ_2")(t)
x1,y1 = l1*sin(th1), -l1*cos(th1)
x2,y2 = x1+l2*sin(th2), y1-l2*cos(th2)

# kinetic energy
vx1,vy1,vx2,vy2 = ( xx.diff(t) for xx in (x1,y1,x2,y2))
K1 = m1/2*(vx1**2+vy1**2)
K2 = m2/2*(vx2**2+vy2**2)
K = K1+K2
# potential energy
V = g*(m1*y1+m2*y2)
# Lagrangian
L = K - V
L = L.expand().simplify()
```

To get an abstract treatment use abstract parameter arrays and coordinate vectors

```py
params = [m1, l1, m2, l2, g]
q = [th1, th2]
dotq = [ qq.diff(t) for qq in q]
```

### From Euler-Lagrange to a first-order ODE system

It gets rather messy in the resulting expressions if one goes to the second derivatives of the angles, one gets a more structured approach and hopefully a correspondingly faster evaluation using impulse variables

```
pk = diff(L, dotqk)
d(pk)/dt = diff(L, qk)
```

where the first relation is seen as a system of equations to compute `dotq` from `p`.

Prepare the new variables, prepare to replace the function symbols with simple variables.

```py
N = len(q)
p = [ Symbol(f"p_{k+1}") for k in range(N)]
dotq_func, dotq = dotq,  [ Symbol(f"Dq_{k+1}") for k in range(N)]
q_func, q = q, [ Symbol(f"q_{k+1}") for k in range(N)]
```

Now replace all function terms by simple variables

```py
L=L.subs(list(zip(dotq_func, dotq))).subs(list(zip(q_func, q)))
```

[image]

Now establish the function to compute `dotq` from `q,p`

```py
p_eqns = [ p[k] - L.diff(dotq[k]) for k in range(N)]
dotq_expr = solve(p_eqns, dotq)
dotq_func = lambdify([*q, *p, *params],[ dotq_expr[dq] for dq in dotq])
```

Next generate a function that computes the derivatives of `p`

```py
dotp_expr = [ L.diff(q[k]) for k in range(N)]
dotp_func = lambdify([*q,*dotq,*params],dotp_expr)
```

Now assemble the generated functions into a complete ODE function and solve a test problem with it to confirm that it works

```py
def odefunc(t,u,args):
    q, p = u[:N], u[N:]
    dotq = dotq_func(*q, *p, *args)
    dotp = dotp_func(*q, *dotq, *args)
    return [*dotq, *dotp]
```

### Confirmation via numerical solution

```py
myparams = [1,10,5,5,9.81]
t = np.linspace(0,25,301)

u = odeint(odefunc,[2,1.2, 0,0],t,args=(myparams,), tfirst=True)

%matplotlib inline
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
plt.plot(t,u[:,0],t,u[:,1]); 
plt.grid(); plt.show()
```

This produces the following plot for the angle functions
[image]

### Outlook

Even better performance could be expected if the kinetic term is (as is usual in classical mechanics) guaranteed to be quadratic in the velocities. Then by directly extracting the matrix of this quadratic form, one could delegate the system solution in the conversion of impuls to velocity to a numerical linear system solver, so not keep the symbolic expressions for the matrix inversion. These could be large in higher dimensions.

Comment: @wrzlprmft: Do you have a suggestion on how to realize this ODE function using JITcode without too much code bloat due to insertion of subexpressions, that is, essentially keep the structure of `odefunc` with `dotq` as intermediate variables, but directly working from `dotq_expr` and `dotp_expr`? I thought that I once read that there was a provision to mark common intermediate expressions, but did not find it again searching now.