# Sympy `lambdify` name 'Derivative' is not defined; can't process from symbolic to numerical; Double Pendulum 3D

Tags: jupyter-notebook, sympy, numerical-methods, derivative, lambdify

Hi i'm trying to write in jupyter notebook a program to calculate and then animate a 3d double pendulum but i've run in many issues; first with the solution dict, i had to decompose it in simpler solution (Lagrangian system) and then group them. Then i tried to use lambdify to change the solution from symbolic to numerical, but i also run in another issue using odeint(..) basically there are still derivatives after lambdify...
https://github.com/Riccardo-Venturi/gpt-help.git
I have two versions but couldn't solve it, best version is the 3D without 22.
@jared f, o are the angles, d(f,O)/dt, dd(f,O) / dt**2
they are the rate of change, you have 4 angles

```
sol_the1_dd = smp.solve(l1_O, O1_dd, dict=True, simplify=False, rational=False)

# Sostituisci la soluzione trovata in LE2 e risolvi per the2_dd
LE2_substituted = l2_O.subs(O1_dd, sol_the1_dd[0][O1_dd])
sol_the2_dd = smp.solve(LE2_substituted, O2_dd, dict=True, simplify=False, rational=False)


# Sostituisci la soluzione trovata in LE3 e risolvi per phi1_dd

LE3_substituted = l1_f.subs(O2_dd, sol_the2_dd[0][O2_dd])
sol_phi1_dd = smp.solve(LE3_substituted, f1_dd, dict=True, simplify=False, rational=False)


# Sostituisci la soluzione trovata in LE4 e risolvi per phi2_dd
LE4_substituted = l2_f.subs(f1_dd, sol_phi1_dd[0][f1_dd])
sol_phi2_dd = smp.solve(LE4_substituted, f2_dd, dict=True, simplify=False, rational=False)

# Visualizza le soluzioni parziali
#print(sol_the1_dd, sol_the2_dd, sol_phi1_dd, sol_phi2_dd)
combined_solutions = {**sol_the1_dd[0], **sol_the2_dd[0], **sol_phi1_dd[0], **sol_phi2_dd[0]}

print("Espressione per the1_dd:", combined_solutions[O1_dd])
print("Espressione per the2_dd:", combined_solutions[O2_dd])
print("Espressione per phi1_dd:", combined_solutions[f1_dd])
print("Espressione per phi2_dd:", combined_solutions[f2_dd])

Espressione per the1_dd: -g*m1*sin(\theta_1(t))/(m1*r1 + m2*r1) - g*m2*sin(\theta_1(t))/(m1*r1 + m2*r1) + m1*r1*sin(\theta_1(t))*cos(\theta_1(t))*Derivative(\phi_1(t), t)**2
```

I Tried this but doesn't work

```
from sympy import Derivative, Function,symbols
# Definizione delle variabili simboliche di funzione
t = symbols('t')
phi1 = Function('phi_1')(t)
phi2 = Function('phi_2')(t)
theta1 = Function('theta_1')(t)
theta2 = Function('theta_2')(t)

# Definizione delle derivate
phi1_d = Derivative(phi1, t)
phi2_dd = Derivative(phi2, t, t)
theta2_d = Derivative(theta2, t)
theta2_dd = Derivative(theta2, t, t)

# Ora puoi utilizzare queste definizioni nelle tue sostituzioni
simplified_the1_dd = combined_solutions[O1_dd].subs({
    phi1_d: f1_d, 
    phi2_dd: f2_dd,
    theta2_d: O2_d,
    theta2_dd: O2_dd
})

# Semplificazione dell'espressione
simplified_the1_dd = smp.simplify(simplified_the1_dd)
# Sostituzioni delle derivate
simplified_the1_dd_substituted = simplified_the1_dd.subs({
    Derivative(phi1, t): f1_d,
    Derivative(phi2, t, t): f2_dd,
    Derivative(theta2, t): O2_d,
    Derivative(theta2, t, t): O2_dd
})

# Ulteriore semplificazione
```

i expected it to chabge the derivative with the variable function and then process it with lambdify to use it in a numerical solution but nothin

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What are `f1_d`, `f2_dd`, `O2_d`, and `O2_dd`? Where are they defined?

Comment: When choosing the category tags and where to post consider the source of the issue and if your code would give you the same result if you ran it as Python code in the console as a traditional script that you pointed Python at on the command line. This is likely a Python issue and so 'jupyter-notebook' should not be a category tag, and [your post definitely shouldn't be crossposted [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/problems-with-conversion-from-symbolic-to-numerical/23374?u=fomightez), especially without linking. You just happen to be running a Python kernel in Jupyter. Jupyter can run ...

Comment: <continued> a lot of language kernels. Python happens to be a very popular one because of the evolution of the Jupyter Project from IPython. Your first sentence does not reflect this: 'Hi i'm trying to write in jupyter notebook a program to calculate'. Why it is always good to at least mention where you are coding in case there's something complicating things, it definitely isn't the priority here. **Importantly keeping things straight will help you search for solutions on the internet using appropriate terms.**

Comment: `sympy.lambdify` translates the sympy expression to a python/numpy function, and has its limits on what it can convert.  The error message probably shows the numpy code. You'll need to force sympy to evaluate that derivative before doing the lambdify.

Comment: Try to do as much as  you can with the `sympy` code itself, possibly even its own plotting. Even with `lambdify`, using `sympy` and `numpy` together is an advanced topic.

Comment: @jared   f, O are the angles, d(f,O)/dt, dd(f,O) / dt**2 they are the rate of change, you have 4 angles

basicaòly it's theta and phi

Comment: @Wayne ok, i'm using latex,too, i can't run it on python so... next time i'll just tag python

Comment: First for the simple solution, sympy has a `mechanical` or similar submodule that also handles Euler-Lagrange equations. For the not so simple solution, you need to substitute first the derivatives back to sympy variables before you lambdify, I went through this journey in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61044226/solving-a-system-of-2nd-order-differential-equations-from-sympy/61078311#61078311

Comment: Your last comment directed at me makes it clearer your thinking and focus. Good on all my first quibbles then but just for reference though I think though you can use latex without Jupyter. I'm pretty sure Latex pre-dates the Jupyter Project by quite a bit? It's just more accessible for displaying these days with Jupyter. That said, I'd go first to Jupyter too if I was needing to involve Latex.

Comment: @Wayne yes, but for some reasons i asked chat gpt and told me the code i was writing wasn't suitable for pure python, so i thought it was specific for jupyter, my bad

Comment: @LutzLehmann i tried, trust me, i tried a lot, for some reason even trying to sympy before lamdify doesn't work, i'll check the link now, but that is what puzzles me, you can find the codes in my link, you'll see u tried it but nada; :(

Comment: ChatGPT is trained to lie convincingly. Because that is the pattern of its source material. Under "lie" I also subsume here rhetorical devices like generalizations, metaphors etc. But the program does not really know reality, so among others can not distinguish what is a harmless and what a harmful half-truth. I would not trust its answers, and especially not its opinions. As said, it is trained to make them convincing, irrespective of factuality. Any search engine with the right keywords will give better answers. The only advantage of jupyter is that it can display the LaTeX results directly.

Comment: `lambdify` only does a basic word-for-word translation of sympy functions into numpy functions, or any other similar provided library, and assembles a python function from it. It does not do symbol substitutions, if it finds a sympy function or construct that can not be translated then it is left as it is. So you really have to prepare and clean up the expressions that you want translated. So if there are derivatives in the state vector, then the derivatives in the expression have first to be replaced with the input symbols.